# Change property of the QML singleton with C++

Tags: c++, qt, singleton, qml, qtquick2

I'm implementing a simplified Ubuntu Touch-like palette (not per-element one).

There is a `GlobalPaletteSetting` singleton:

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick 2.5

QtObject {
    property Palette current: NonePalette {}
}
```

and some palette classes like `NonePalette` or `Dark`:

```
Palette {
    normal: PaletteValues {
        background: "white"
        backgroundText: "black"
        base: "white"
        baseText: "black"
        foreground: "white"
        foregroundText: "black"
        overlay: "white"
        overlayText: "black"
        field: "white"
        fieldText: "black"
        selection: "pink"
    }
}
```

So, the global palette can be changed in QML:

```
import "Customization/Palettes/Dark"

//...

DarkPalette {
    id: dark
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    GlobalPaletteSetting.current = dark
}
```

I want to set the global palette by setting the environment variable. Just like the QtQuick styles are working.

So, an access to `GlobalPaletteSetting` is needed from C++. And also a method to load QML files with palettes and setting the `GlobalPaletteSetting.current`.

How to do that?

Comment: Where did you instance `GlobalPaletteSetting` object? In fact I guess it is not singleton since you can create several instances of an object. Anyway you can define `objectName` for your singleton in `QML` and access it from C++: `rootObject.findChild<QObject *>("someObjectName")`

Comment: `GlobalPaletteSetting` is a singleton (`pragma singleton`). Added header to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code I came up with:

```
QQmlComponent component(engine());
const char *source =
        "import QtQuick 2.0\n"
        "import Components 1.0\n"
        "QtObject {\n"
        "    property var style: CustomStyle\n"
        "    function setColor(c) { CustomStyle.headerColor = c; }\n"
        "}";
component.setData(source, QUrl());
QObject *item = component.create();
QObject *style = qvariant_cast<QObject*>(item->property("style"));
style->setProperty("headerColor", QColor(255, 0, 0));
```

Here, `CustomStyle` is my style definition, a singleton. You can find a complete example at https://goo.gl/ItJGIf

The recommendation to use `objectName` did not work for me - whether I put it at the top level of my singleton component, or in a child item, `findChild` returns 0. It also does not work on top-level of regular components, only children thereof. You can find my attempt at https://goo.gl/Iqj9Ap

Regarding your second question, about loading your style definition at runtime, you can adjust the above code - use `setData` or `loadUrl` to load component definition, use `create` to create an instance, and then set the instance. In fact, you can do `engine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("style", ...)` so that everything in your QML can access 'style' variable, which might be easier than having a singleton.

Comment: Yes, the trick with `objectName` will not work since a singleton have no parent (parent is `null`).

Comment: Haven't added this to my project yet, but it is the solution. Basically, creating in C++ a QtObject that points to the singleton. Unrelated note about styles: I'm using custom QtQuick styles that can be selected through standard `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_STYLE` env var. Now I can add another env var to select which palette styles will use.

Comment: Hey, your answer seems like what I'm looking for, but I can't get it to work. I have a Singleton in my project set up the same as yours, and I'm using it throughout my QML files. I want to be able in some circumstances to programmatically alter one of the properties of this Singleton. I'm not sure exactly where to put the code in your sample.

Comment: I assume you wish to modify properties of the Singleton from C++? Then, you would need to store the 'style' in the above code example in a class member, and use the last two lines of the example to modify a property when you need it. Is there any problem you're running into?